# Traversing a complete graph

Tags: graph-theory

In a complete undirected graph, each edge has a positive weight distinct from any other edge. $A$ and $B$ want to visit all vertices, not necessarily starting from the same vertex. $A$ always chooses the edge with the highest weight to an unvisited vertex, while $B$ always chooses the edge with the lowest weight to an unvisited vertex. Is it always the case that the sum of the weights of the edges that $A$ traverses is at least that of $B$?

When there are two vertices, the sums of $A$ and $B$ are always equal. If there are three vertices, suppose the three edges have weight $a\geq b\geq c$. Then the sum of $A$ is at least $a+c$, while the sum of $B$ is at most $a+c$, so the statement is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true; in fact we can show that for every weight $w$, $B$ never chooses more edges of weight $\geq w$ than $A$.

[Proof below fixed after @Karo pointed out an error - thanks!]

To see this, write $a, b$ for the number of edges $\geq w$ each use. Look at all the vertices $B$ leaves using such an edge. All the edges between these must be $\geq w$, and the same is true for all edges between these vertices and the last vertex $B$ visits. So that gives $b+1$ vertices and all edges between them are $\geq w$.

Conversely, all edges between vertices $A$ left using an edge with weight $<w$, or from these to $A$'s final vertex, are $<w$, and this is $n-a$ vertices in total.

There can be at most one vertex in both sets, so $b+1+n-a\leq n+1$, i.e. $a\geq b$.

Comment: "All the edges between them must be $\geq w$" But if $B$ uses edges $a-b$ and $c-d$ with weight at least $w$, it doesn't mean that the edge $b-c$ has weight at least $w$, does it?

Comment: @Karo Ah, I think you're right, thanks. What we actually need is the set of vertices $B$ leaves with such an edge, plus his final vertex. Will edit to give a correct version.

Comment: Nice solution !